# Query using IN keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, in-operator

I am learning how to write TSQL queries. I am trying to understand them in depth. This query that I got from a tutorial requires that I check for a NOT NULL in the second WHERE clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM Person.Person AS p
WHERE NOT p.BusinessEntityID IN (
    SELECT PersonID
    FROM Sales.Customer
    WHERE PersonID IS NOT NULL);
```

Now the table Sales.Customer has some NULL values for PersonID. If I remove this WHERE clause in the sub query, I get no results returned. In my obviously faulty thinking on the matter, I would think that if the sub query returned a NULL it would simply not meet the condition of the WHERE clause in the outer query. I would expect to get a result set for the rows that had a PersonID that is not NULL. Why does it not work according to this reasoning?

Comment: This query appears to be trying to produce a result of people that are not yet customers. You are saying give me a list of rows from Persons.Person where its BusinessEntityId is NOT in list of non-NULL values. Tthe subquery specifically says where Persons is NOT null so it would return either an empty set or a set of non-null values..

Comment: Understanding how NULL values are handled by SQL Server can be difficult for newcomers.  A value of NULL indicates that the value is unknown. A value of NULL is different from an empty or zero value. No two null values are equal. Comparisons between two null values, or between a NULL and any other value, return unknown because the value of each NULL is unknown.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @DMason you should make your comment as the answer.

Comment: @DMason you have the correct answer. Post it as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understanding how NULL values are handled by SQL Server can be difficult for newcomers. A value of NULL indicates that the value is unknown. A value of NULL is different from an empty or zero value. No two null values are equal. Comparisons between two null values, or between a NULL and any other value, return unknown because the value of each NULL is unknown.

[Null Values](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

A little change as shown below (`column not in`)

```
SELECT *
FROM Person AS p
WHERE p.BusinessEntityID NOT IN (  <-- Here
    SELECT PersonID
    FROM Sales.Customer
    WHERE PersonID IS NOT NULL);
```

Your inner query returns all non-null personid and outer query getting all fields 
from person table with restriction that BusinessEntityID doesn't belong to personid.

Answer (score 0):

A NULL can also be explained as UNKNOWN, so if a single NULL is returned from your subquery SQL Server returns no rows because it does not know if a value is or is not contained in the result.